# The function that takes two quotient sets and merges them

Tags: set-theory, equivalence-relations, quotient-set

I want to know the definition and the well-definedness
of the function that takes two quotient sets (disjoint-set data structures), merges them
and returns a quotient set.

For example, if the function takes two inputs,
{{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}, {6, 7}} and
{{2, 6}, {8}},
then it returns
{{1, 2, 6, 7}, {3, 4, 5}, {8}}.

Please let me know if you have the answer (or the reference to these discussions).
I am also very pleased if you let me know that you do not have the answer
(this is not common knowledge).

## Q1.

Is there any (common) definition of this function?

## Q2.

Is that function well-defined,
i.e., the function always returns output, and the output is uniquely determined by the inputs?

## Remark

I wrote a pseudo-code of this function (in a functional programming style).

```
let rec merge QS =
  if \exists S, S' \in QS.
    S \neq S' \land S \cap S' \neq \emptyset
  then
    merge (\{S \cup S'\} \cup ((SS \setminus S) \setminus S'))
  else
    QS

let merge_quotient_sets QS QS' =
  merge (QS \cup QS')
```

However, I found that

1. This seems too "algorithmic" and does not seems like a "mathematical definition".
2. I could not give well-definedness proof (which may not be difficult though).

Can someone give me a simpler and more algebraic(?) definition and an elegant proof?

Comment: Please explain the output in the example !

Comment: Thank you for the comment.

In this example, the function merges
A = \{\{1, 2\}, \{3, 4, 5\}, \{6, 7\}\}
and
B = \{\{2, 6\}, \{8\}\}.
Since
\{1, 2\} in A,
\{2, 6\} in A and
\{6, 7\} in B
overlaps,
they are merged in a set
\{1, 2, 6, 7\}
in the output.
Since there are no more overlaps,
the rest sets \{3, 4, 5\} in A and \{8\} in B
are just returned as they were in the input sets.
Thus, the output will be
\{\{1, 2, 6, 7\}, \{3, 4, 5\}, \{8\}\}.

I will give more explanation about examples when I ask a question next time.
Thunk you!

Answer (score 1):

What you have called a quotient set or a disjoint data structure, I would call a partition of a set. It's a standard fact that every partition of a set arises from a unique equivalence relation on that set, namely that $x\sim y$ if and only if $x$ and $y$ are in the same subset in the partition. In these terms, the operation you are describing, starting from two equivalence relations $R_1$ and $R_2$, seems to be the equivalence relation generated by $R_1\cup R_2$, which is the smallest equivalence relation containing both $R_1$ and $R_2$.

Comment: Thats exactly what I want! Thank you so much!!!